# What "max_connections" really mean in Envoy?

Tags: istio, circuit-breaker, envoyproxy

My question is about what "cluster.CircuitBreakers.Thresholds.max_connections" really mean in [Envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/).

**cluster.CircuitBreakers.Thresholds.max_connections** in [envoy doc](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/api/v2/cluster/circuit_breaker.proto.html?highlight=max_connection) is explained as :

> The maximum number of connections that Envoy will make to the upstream cluster. If not specified, the default is 1024.

[Istio](https://istio.io/) uses envoy as a sidecar. Recently we tried the circuit breaking sample but always found that there are more connections than we configured.

So we make another test shown below:

1. Add two services into istio:

   - echo client: 1 pod, downstream, will send HTTP request to echo server
   - echo server: 2 pods, upstream.

the service pods:

```
[root@k8s-master istio-1.0.3]# kubectl get pod -o wide
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP            NODE     NOMINATED NODE
echoclient-84485fbc5c-zxlv8   2/2     Running   0          8s      10.244.2.79   node02   <none>
echoserver-5655768fb9-smsvb   2/2     Running   0          23h     10.244.2.65   node02   <none>
echoserver-5655768fb9-srsq2   2/2     Running   0          7h52m   10.244.2.73   node02   <none>
```

2. Configured destination rule for echo server, below shows the corresponding info in the envoy. (maxConnections is 2)

istio proxy-config output:

```
[root@k8s-master istio-1.0.3]# istioctl proxy-config clusters echoclient-84485fbc5c-zxlv8 --fqdn echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local -o json
[
    {
        "name": "outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local",
        "type": "EDS",
        "edsClusterConfig": {
            "edsConfig": {
                "ads": {}
            },
            "serviceName": "outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local"
        },
        "connectTimeout": "1.000s",
        "circuitBreakers": {
            "thresholds": [
                {
                    "maxConnections": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

3. Make multiple requests concurrently(40 requests per thread) from echo client to each server.

results:

```
[root@k8s-master istio-1.0.3]# kubectl exec -it echoclient-84485fbc5c-zxlv8 /bin/bash
Defaulting container name to echoclient.
Use 'kubectl describe pod/echoclient-84485fbc5c-zxlv8 -n default' to see all of the containers in this pod.
[root@echoclient-84485fbc5c-zxlv8 /]# /opt/jre/bin/java -cp /opt/echoclient-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar hello.HttpSender "http://echoserver:8080/echo?name=peter" 10 40 0
using num threads: 10
Starting pool-1-thread-1 with numCalls=40 parallelSends=false delayBetweenCalls=0 url=http://echoserver:8080/echo?name=peter mixedRespTimes=false
Starting pool-1-thread-2 with numCalls=40 parallelSends=false delayBetweenCalls=0 url=http://echoserver:8080/echo?name=peter mixedRespTimes=false
Starting pool-1-thread-3 with numCalls=40 parallelSends=false delayBetweenCalls=0 url=http://echoserver:8080/echo?name=peter mixedRespTimes=false
Starting pool-1-thread-4 with numCalls=40 parallelSends=false delayBetweenCalls=0 url=http://echoserver:8080/echo?name=peter mixedRespTimes=false
Starting pool-1-thread-5 with numCalls=40 parallelSends=false delayBetweenCalls=0 url=http://echoserver:8080/echo?name=peter mixedRespTimes=false
Starting pool-1-thread-6 with numCalls=40 parallelSends=false delayBetweenCalls=0 url=http://echoserver:8080/echo?name=peter mixedRespTimes=false
Starting pool-1-thread-7 with numCalls=40 parallelSends=false delayBetweenCalls=0 url=http://echoserver:8080/echo?name=peter mixedRespTimes=false
Starting pool-1-thread-8 with numCalls=40 parallelSends=false delayBetweenCalls=0 url=http://echoserver:8080/echo?name=peter mixedRespTimes=false
Starting pool-1-thread-9 with numCalls=40 parallelSends=false delayBetweenCalls=0 url=http://echoserver:8080/echo?name=peter mixedRespTimes=false
Starting pool-1-thread-10 with numCalls=40 parallelSends=false delayBetweenCalls=0 url=http://echoserver:8080/echo?name=peter mixedRespTimes=false
pool-1-thread-7: successes=[40], failures=[0], duration=[481ms]
pool-1-thread-6: successes=[40], failures=[0], duration=[485ms]
pool-1-thread-4: successes=[40], failures=[0], duration=[504ms]
pool-1-thread-1: successes=[40], failures=[0], duration=[542ms]
pool-1-thread-9: successes=[40], failures=[0], duration=[626ms]
pool-1-thread-8: successes=[40], failures=[0], duration=[652ms]
pool-1-thread-2: successes=[40], failures=[0], duration=[684ms]
pool-1-thread-10: successes=[40], failures=[0], duration=[657ms]
pool-1-thread-5: successes=[40], failures=[0], duration=[678ms]
pool-1-thread-3: successes=[40], failures=[0], duration=[696ms]
```

4. Check the HTTP connection from echo client to echo server

connection info from netstat:

```
[root@echoclient-84485fbc5c-zxlv8 /]# netstat -ano | grep 8080 | grep ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.244.2.79:58074       10.244.2.65:8080        ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.244.2.79:38076       10.244.2.73:8080        ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.244.2.79:58088       10.244.2.65:8080        ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.244.2.79:38080       10.244.2.73:8080        ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.244.2.79:58056       10.244.2.65:8080        ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.244.2.79:38094       10.244.2.73:8080        ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.244.2.79:38110       10.244.2.73:8080        ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 10.244.2.79:58076       10.244.2.65:8080        ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
```

connection info from envoy cluster:

```
[root@echoclient-84485fbc5c-zxlv8 /]# curl -s http://localhost:15000/clusters | grep echoserver
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::default_priority::max_connections::2
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::default_priority::max_pending_requests::1024
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::default_priority::max_requests::1024
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::default_priority::max_retries::3
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::high_priority::max_connections::1024
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::high_priority::max_pending_requests::1024
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::high_priority::max_requests::1024
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::high_priority::max_retries::3
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::added_via_api::true
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.65:8080::cx_active::4
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.65:8080::cx_connect_fail::0
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.65:8080::cx_total::4
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.65:8080::rq_active::0
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.65:8080::rq_error::0
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.65:8080::rq_success::200
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.65:8080::rq_timeout::0
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.65:8080::rq_total::200
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.65:8080::health_flags::healthy
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.65:8080::weight::1
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.65:8080::region::
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.65:8080::zone::
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.65:8080::sub_zone::
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.65:8080::canary::false
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.65:8080::success_rate::-1
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.73:8080::cx_active::4
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.73:8080::cx_connect_fail::0
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.73:8080::cx_total::4
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.73:8080::rq_active::0
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.73:8080::rq_error::0
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.73:8080::rq_success::200
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.73:8080::rq_timeout::0
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.73:8080::rq_total::200
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.73:8080::health_flags::healthy
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.73:8080::weight::1
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.73:8080::region::
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.73:8080::zone::
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.73:8080::sub_zone::
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.73:8080::canary::false
outbound|8080||echoserver.default.svc.cluster.local::10.244.2.73:8080::success_rate::-1
```

We can see that there are **8 connections** from echoclient to echoserver(10.244.2.65,10.244.2.73), but **not the configured maxConnections 2**.

Why there are 8 connections but not 2? 
Is there any misunderstanding about the maxConnections of envoy?

Comment: `max_connections` or `max_requests` refers to the number of connections each `children` of the php pool can take before it respawns and can be typically found in `/etc/etc/php/{version}/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

`max_children` is based on the memory of the machine, some example tutorials that were helpful for me to understand were [Max Requests / Children](https://medium.com/@richb_/tweaking-nginx-and-php-fpm-configuration-to-fix-502-bad-gateway-errors-and-optimise-performance-on-17465f41fd87)

Answer (score 2):

As Garrett mention in comments:

`max_connections` or `max_requests` refers to the number of connections each `children` of the php pool can take before it respawns and can be typically found in `/etc/etc/php/{version}/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` `max_children` is based on the memory of the machine, some example tutorials that were helpful for me to understand were [Max Requests / Children](https://medium.com/@richb_/tweaking-nginx-and-php-fpm-configuration-to-fix-502-bad-gateway-errors-and-optimise-performance-on-17465f41fd87)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you invoked the client with 1 thread (ie, 1 HTTP connection) but it sends requests in parallel (in batches of 10 by default)

In envoy, **max_connections** apply to http1 connections and in your case, you have just a single http connection.

Try taking a look at **`max_request`** which apply potentially to threads that have a close relation to http2.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

SSH to node of client pod, and exec into istio-proxy container

`docker exec --privileged --user root  -it <istio-proxy-container-id> bash`

Use following command to find tcp connections envoy make to upstream

`ss -pe | grep 8080 | grep envoy`

Answer (score 0):

I think envoy can make upstream connections up to max_connections per one envoy worker. If you run envoy with one concurrency option, you can check only two upstream connections are created.

```
$ envoy -c envoy.yaml --concurrency 1
```